# Java 8 : Convert List<ObjectA> into List<ObjectB> by grouping and summing over different fields using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to understand java 8 streams. I have two classes.

```
public class ObjectA {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private String fieldC;
    private double valueA;
    private double valueB;
    private double valueC;      
}

public class ObjectB {
    private String fieldA;
    private double valueA;
    private double valueB;
    private double valueC; 
}
```

I am trying to convert `List<ObjectA>` into `List<ObjectB>` by grouping over `fieldA` and summing `valueA`, `valueB`, `valueC` using streams, but can't exactly figure out how to do it.

Here is what I want to do :

```
Map<String,ObjectB> fieldCObjectBMap = new HashMap<>();

for(ObjectA objectA : objectAList) {
  if(fieldCObjectBMap.size != 0 && fieldCObjectBMap.keyset().contains(objectA.getFieldC)) {
    ObjectB objectB = fieldCObjectBMap.get(objectA.getFieldC);
    objectB.setValueA(objectB.getValueA()+objectA.getValueA());
    objectB.setValueB(objectB.getValueB()+objectA.getValueB());
    objectB.setValueC(objectB.getValueC()+objectA.getValueC());
    fieldCObjectBMap.put(objectA.getFieldC,objectB);
  } else {
    ObjectB objectB = fieldCObjectBMap.get(objectA.getFieldC);
    objectB.setValueA(objectA.getValueA());
    objectB.setValueB(objectA.getValueB());
    objectB.setValueC(objectA.getValueC());
    fieldCObjectBMap.put(objectA.getFieldC,objectB);
  }
}

List<ObjectB> objectBList = fieldCObjectBMap.values();
```

Comment: Start with a `groupBy`, followed by a `flatMap` and another `map`.

Comment: Give sample example. For example what are the field values in A and how they are transformed to B and final field values of B. If possible write simple code for transforming A to B without stream. Then we will be able to understand better what you want.

Comment: The example that you provided will throw a `NullPointerException` due to you attempting to retrieve and modify a value in the `Map` that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JacobG. edited.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion for a converter from `List<ObjectA>` to `List<ObjectB>` with the rules you describe:

```
class AtoBCollector {
    private static ObjectB makeFromA(ObjectA a) {
        return new ObjectB(a.getFieldA(), a.getValueA(), a.getValueB(), a.getValueC());
    }

    private static BinaryOperator<ObjectB> reduceB = (b1, b2) ->
        new ObjectB(b1.getFieldA(),
                    b1.getValueA() + b2.getValueA(),
                    b1.getValueB() + b2.getValueB(),
                    b1.getValueC() + b2.getValueC());

    static List<ObjectB> collect(List<ObjectA> objectAList) {
        return new ArrayList<>(objectAList.stream()
            .map(AtoBCollector::makeFromA)
            .collect(toMap(ObjectB::getFieldA, identity(), reduceB))
            .values());
    }
}
```

What [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) does is : The first time a value of `fieldA` is encountered, it will put it to a `Map<String, ObjectB>` as key with value the corresponding instance of `ObjectB`. The next times it will merge two `ObjectB` instances with `reduceB`.

Note that `values()` returns a `Collection` and you have to explicitly create a `List`. In many cases you can use the `Collection` directly and that's preferable.

As alternative to the above you can inline `makeFromA` and `reduceB` and skip the definition of `AtoBCollector`. That resulting code will be considered less readable by some people. Exercise your best judgement.

As another alternative, if the source code of `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` is under your control, you can implement the functionality of `makeFromA` as a constructor of `ObjectB` and/or `reduceB` as a method of `ObjectB`.

Comment: I wouldn't have returned a new `ObjectB` instance in the merge function. Instead, I would have reduced into the received `b1` argument.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `Collectors.toMap` as @Manos Nikolaidis did in his answer. Another way is to use a custom collector. I will do this inside a static helper method, using a local class `Acc` to accumulate partial results:

```
static Collector<ObjectA, ?, ObjectB> summingFields() {

    class Acc {
        ObjectB b = new ObjectB();

        void sum(ObjectA a) {
            this.b.setFieldA(a.getFieldA());
            this.b.setValueA(b.getValueA() + a.getValueA());
            this.b.setValueB(b.getValueB() + a.getValueB());
            this.b.setValueC(b.getValueC() + a.getValueC());
        }

        Acc merge(Acc other) {
            this.b.setValueA(this.b.getValueA() + other.b.getValueA());
            this.b.setValueB(this.b.getValueB() + other.b.getValueB());
            this.b.setValueC(this.b.getValueC() + other.b.getValueC());
            return this;
        }

        ObjectB getB() {
            return this.b;
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::sum, Acc::merge, Acc::getB);
}
```

This uses the method [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-), which creates a custom collector based on its arguments. Then, you could use the `summingFields` method to get a `Collection<ObjectB>` as follows:

```
Collection<ObjectB> grouped = objectAList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        ObjectA::getFieldA,
        summingFields()))
    .values();
```

---

However, everything would be much easier if you could add the following couple of methods in your `ObjectB` class:

```
public void sum(ObjectA a) {
    this.fieldA = a.getFieldA();
    this.valueA += a.getValueA();
    this.valueB += a.getValueB();
    this.valueC += a.getValueC();
}

public ObjectB merge(ObjectB b) {
    this.valueA += b.getValueA();
    this.valueB += b.getValueB();
    this.valueC += b.getValueC();
    return this;
}
```

Then, you could use `Collector.of` with these methods:

```
Collection<ObjectB> grouped = objectAList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        ObjectA::getFieldA,
        Collector.of(ObjectB::new, ObjectB::sum, ObjectB::merge)))
    .values();
```